# Show picture in android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

I've written a quiz app with one question and three answers.

The questions and answers are saved in a `Frage` object. For example:

```
Frage f6 = new Frage(7, "Welche Notrufnummer hat die Rettung in Österreich?", 
                     "166", "144", "110", "144", "bronze");
```

Now I want to extend the whole thing that I can show a picture, a question to this pictures and three answers again. 
What is the best way to implement that? How can I save pictures in my app?

**Edit:** As I´m on the very beginning of Android developing, I´m not sure how to connect the picture and my questions. 
The best way might be to name the pictures with the id of the appropiate question, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You save your picture in your asset or drawable folder and show them via

Drawable:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this); // (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.imageview);
iv.setImageResource( R.drawable.picture );
```

Assets:

```
try 
{
    // get input stream
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    iv.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

In your case maybe save the resource id in your "Frage" object and give it your imageviee.

```
Frage f6 = new Frage(7, "Welche Notrufnummer hat die Rettung in Österreich?", 
                     "166", "144", "110", "144", "bronze",R.drawable.austria_emergency_call);
```

besten Gruß

Comment: Ok thanks, I´ll try it, thanks for your help(Will accept it if it works)! Besten Gruß

Comment: No problem :). In your case it should work. But as you save your question in a database I wouldn't use the R id. Because the values(integers) may change over time(app update). In database I would use the Assets way and save the file name.